# Passing request attributes to the welcome-file running in glassfish

Tags: jsp, servlets, glassfish, web.xml

Is there a way to set attributes for a JSP file acting as the welcome-file for a web application? I've seen a lot of posts describing the purpose and and scenarios of the welcome-file tag in web.xml but nothing as far as setting attributes for the associated HttpServletRequest.

thanks!

Comment: What else would you like to know? I'm using glassfish to serve several pages but none of my particular servlets redirect to this particular JSP...because it's already served by some glassfish magic as it is indicated to be the welcome-page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I was looking to do by changing the welcome-file to point to a url pattern of a separate servlet. Inside this servlet's processRequest() method, I add the attribute and redirect to original JSP it was pointing to. I'm still unsure of how to set attributes without redirection from a servlet, but something tells me it might be container-dependent i.e. glassfish and tomcat might do it differently.